# Solve $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{1+x^2}dx$ Using Methods From Complex analysis

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, improper-integrals, contour-integration

I am practising some complex analysis material as I a still very new to this area of mathematics and I found the question:$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{1+x^2}dx$$
How would I even begin to solve this?

Comment: Semicircle contour with e^(ix) replacing cos(x) perhaps?

Comment: apply residue theorem on $\{re^{i\theta} \mid r>1,\theta \in [0,\pi]\}\cup\{t\mid t\in (-r,r)\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\int_{\gamma}\dfrac{e^{ix}}{1+x^2}dx$ with "an upper semicircle plus a diameter" contour $\gamma$ with radius $R\gt 1$. Then $\int_{\gamma}\dfrac{e^{ix}}{1+x^2}dx=\dfrac {\pi}e$. Let $f(x)=\dfrac{e^{ix}}{1+x^2}$ and the semicircle contour $\Gamma$, since $|\int_{\Gamma} f(x) dx|\le\int_{\Gamma}\dfrac{|e^{ix}|}{1+|x|^2}|dx|\le\dfrac{\pi R}{R^2+1}\to 0$ as $R\to \infty, \dfrac{\pi}e=\lim_{R\to\infty}(\int_{-R}^{R}\dfrac{\cos x}{1+x^2}dx+i\int_{-R}^{R}\dfrac{\sin x}{1+x^2}dx)$ and thus $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos x}{1+x^2}dx=\dfrac{\pi}e$.

Comment: This is my homework XD.

Comment: Hi @Divide1918! Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question. Why do we take the upper semicircle to be the contour rather than the lower semicircle?

Comment: I think you can use lower semicircle as well, but the residue might be different. I'm not entirely sure as I'm not far into learning about complex residue myself as well. But I recommend you to go through the argument using the lower semicircle.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\cos(x)=Re[\exp(ix)]$, you may want to look at $\int_\gamma \frac{\exp(iz)}{z^2 + 1}dz=\int_\gamma\frac{\exp(iz)}{(z - i)(z + i)}dz$. In complex analysis, these types of integrals are evaluated by utilizing Cauchy's residue theorem. So perhaps you want to use a closed contour $\gamma=\gamma_0+\gamma_1$, and the idea here is that $\gamma_0$ is going to simply be the path on the real line from $-R$ to $R$. Meanwhile, $\gamma_1$ is going to be an arc of a circle enclosing one of the poles, and the endpoints of $\gamma_1$ should coincide with those of $\gamma_0$ in order for Cauchy's residue theorem to work. With this breakdown, you have that $$\oint_\gamma\frac{\exp(iz)}{(z - i)(z + i)}dz=\int_{\gamma_0}\frac{\exp(iz)}{(z - i)(z + i)} dz+\int_{\gamma_1}\frac{exp(iz)}{(z - i)(z + i)}dz,$$ where $$\int_{\gamma_0}\frac{\exp(iz)}{(z - i)(z + i)}dz=\int_{-R}^R\frac{\exp(it)}{t^2+1}dt$$ and $$\int_{\gamma_1}\frac{exp(iz)}{(z - i)(z + i)}dz = \int_0^{\pi}\frac{\exp(iR\exp(it))}{(R\exp(it))^2+1}iR\exp(it)dt$$ since $\gamma_1(t) = R\exp(it), t \in [0, \pi]$. As such, $$\int_{-R}^R\frac{\exp(it)}{t^2+1}dt=\oint_\gamma\frac{\exp(iz)}{(z - i)(z + i)}dz-\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\exp(iR\exp(it))}{(R\exp(it))^2+1}iR\exp(it)dt.$$ From here, computing the integral you want should be a very straightforward exercise, using Cauchy's residue theorem, and Jordan's lemma. I will leave up that part to finish for yourself.

Comment: Why can we use $e^{iz}$ if $\text{cos}(x)=\text{Re}(e^{ix})$?

Comment: @Diaz.Mrn You can just take the real part of the end result of the integral to obtain the result you desire. This is intentional.